# About ionic tabs bar hidden promblem

Tags: ionic-framework

Please see my code:

http://codepen.io/FrostD/pen/QyyXaQ?editors=101

```
<html ng-app="ionicApp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">

    <title>Tabs Example</title>

    <link href="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>

    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">
      <ion-nav-back-button>
      </ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-bar>

    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>


    <script id="templates/tabs.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top tabs-positive" ng-class="{'tabs-item-hide': $root.hideTabs}">

        <ion-tab title="Home" icon="ion-home" href="#/tab/home">
          <ion-nav-view name="home-tab"></ion-nav-view>
        </ion-tab>

        <ion-tab title="About" icon="ion-ios-information" href="#/tab/about">
          <ion-nav-view name="about-tab"></ion-nav-view>
        </ion-tab>

        <ion-tab title="Contact" icon="ion-ios-world" ui-sref="tabs.contact">
          <ion-nav-view name="contact-tab"></ion-nav-view>
        </ion-tab>

      </ion-tabs>
    </script>

    <script id="templates/home.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-view view-title="Home">
        <ion-content class="padding">
          <p>
            <a class="button icon icon-right ion-chevron-right" href="#/tab/facts">Scientific Facts</a>
          </p>
        </ion-content>
      </ion-view>
    </script>

    <script id="templates/facts.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-view cache-view="false" id="store-visit-wrapper" hide-tabs="true">
        <ion-content class="padding">
          <p>This page should not show the tab-bar at the bottom</p>
          <p>Banging your head against a wall uses 150 calories an hour.</p>
          <p>Dogs have four toes on their hind feet, and five on their front feet.</p>
          <p>The ant can lift 50 times its own weight, can pull 30 times its own weight and always falls over on its right side when intoxicated.</p>
          <p>A cockroach will live nine days without it's head, before it starves to death.</p>
          <p>Polar bears are left handed.</p>
          <p>
            <a class="button icon ion-home" href="#/tab/home"> Home</a>
            <a class="button icon icon-right ion-chevron-right" href="#/tab/facts2">More Facts</a>
          </p>
        </ion-content>
      </ion-view>
    </script>

    <script id="templates/facts2.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-view view-title="Also Factual" hide-tabs="true">
        <ion-content class="padding">
          <p>111,111,111 x 111,111,111 = 12,345,678,987,654,321</p>
          <p>1 in every 4 Americans has appeared on T.V.</p>
          <p>11% of the world is left-handed.</p>
          <p>1 in 8 Americans has worked at a McDonalds restaurant.</p>
          <p>$283,200 is the absolute highest amount of money you can win on Jeopardy.</p>
          <p>101 Dalmatians, Peter Pan, Lady and the Tramp, and Mulan are the only Disney cartoons where both parents are present and don't die throughout the movie.</p>
          <p>
            <a class="button icon ion-home" href="#/tab/home"> Home</a>
            <a class="button icon ion-chevron-left" href="#/tab/facts"> Scientific Facts</a>
          </p>
        </ion-content>
      </ion-view>
    </script>

    <script id="templates/about.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-view view-title="About">
        <ion-content class="padding">
          <h3>Create hybrid mobile apps with the web technologies you love.</h3>
          <p>Free and open source, Ionic offers a library of mobile-optimized HTML, CSS and JS components for building highly interactive apps.</p>
          <p>Built with Sass and optimized for AngularJS.</p>
          <p>
            <a class="button icon icon-right ion-chevron-right" href="#/tab/navstack">Tabs Nav Stack</a>
          </p>
        </ion-content>
      </ion-view>
    </script>

    <script id="templates/nav-stack.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-view view-title="Tab Nav Stack">
        <ion-content class="padding">
          <p><img src="http://ionicframework.com/img/diagrams/tabs-nav-stack.png" style="width:100%"></p>
        </ion-content>
      </ion-view>
    </script>

    <script id="templates/contact.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-view title="Contact">
        <ion-content>
          <div class="list">
            <div class="item">
              @IonicFramework
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              @DriftyTeam
            </div>
          </div>
        </ion-content>
      </ion-view>
    </script>

  </body>
</html>


angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider
    .state('tabs', {
      url: "/tab",
      abstract: true,
      templateUrl: "templates/tabs.html"
    })
    .state('tabs.home', {
      url: "/home",
      views: {
        'home-tab': {
          templateUrl: "templates/home.html",
          controller: 'HomeTabCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tabs.facts', {
      url: "/facts",
      views: {
        'home-tab': {
          templateUrl: "templates/facts.html"
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tabs.facts2', {
      url: "/facts2",
      views: {
        'home-tab': {
          templateUrl: "templates/facts2.html"
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tabs.about', {
      url: "/about",
      views: {
        'about-tab': {
          templateUrl: "templates/about.html"
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tabs.navstack', {
      url: "/navstack",
      views: {
        'about-tab': {
          templateUrl: "templates/nav-stack.html"
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tabs.contact', {
      url: "/contact",
      views: {
        'contact-tab': {
          templateUrl: "templates/contact.html"
        }
      }
    });


   $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/tab/home");

})

.controller('HomeTabCtrl', function($scope) {
  console.log('HomeTabCtrl');
})

.directive('hideTabs', function($rootScope) {
  return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
                scope.$watch(attributes.hideTabs, function(value){
                    console.log('$watch value=' + value);
                    $rootScope.hideTabs = value;
                });
                scope.$on('$ionicView.beforeLeave', function () {
                    console.log('$ionicView.beforeLeave');
                    $rootScope.hideTabs = false;
                });
            }
  };
});
```

In home tab, click Scientific Facts button and go to next page, tabs bar is hidden, works well.
Next, click More Facts button to go to next page, but tabs bar is not hidden.
I don't know why,  $rootScope.hideTabs is true, but tabs bar is still here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove **directive** ***"hideTabs"***

```
.directive('hideTabs', function($rootScope) {
    ......
});
```

and add following simple code, its working fine.

```
.run(function($rootScope, $location, $ionicPlatform) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {    
        $rootScope.$on("$locationChangeStart", function(event, next, current)     {
            if ($location.url() == '/tab/facts2' || $location.url() == '/tab/facts') {               
                $rootScope.hideTabs = true;
            }else{
                $rootScope.hideTabs = false;
            }  
        });
    });
})
```

Comment: Thanks, you're right. Your solution is same as mine.